# crystal report for visual studio 2010 is not displaying after hosting on remote server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i developed an asp.net application in which i used crystal report (for visual studio 2010). I have a big problem that is when i run my application on local server, it works fine but when i deploy it on remote server, crystal report is not displaying. can any one help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that an appropriate version of crystal report run-time is installed on deployment (remote) server or not.

Answer (score 0):

make sure temp directory of windows have appropriate permissions to execute the report. In my case I gave full permission to everyone on c:\windows\temp directory.

visit following link to find the step by step solution to deploy a crystal report website.

http://dubeyniraj.blogspot.in/2012/02/deploying-net-crystal-report-website-on.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Andrew, Please advice me how to write a disclaimer. The link to my blog is given only because I may be updating the blog post with any other new problem I face related to this question when I m working some other time on the similar issue, it is not possible to update the same on all the posts I make, correct me if I am wrong.